# Set default application server Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

I have multiple application servers on my classpath, namely Netty via spring-boot-starter-webflux and Tomcat through another dependency chain. How can I determine which application server to use in Spring Boot?

Currently, Tomcat is being started instead Netty.

Important note: I can't exclude any of them, Tomcat is used by CXF, Netty is used by WebClient.

Answer (score 0):

Just use proper spring-boot-starter-package

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html

In your case it will be probably `spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty`

Also it would be wise to exclude multiple JEE embedded containers and remove those you don't need.

Comment: I've included starter Jetty for testing purposes in a totally empty web mvc project and it still starts Tomcat. I can't exclude Tomcat because CXF depends on it. Is there a config where I can select from the available containers?

Comment: I didn't find any clue in them. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the application is reactive directly in you configuration at startup something like this

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        springApplication.setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.REACTIVE);
        springApplication.run(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, both Netty and Tomcat supports REACTIVE, but this is the closest suggestion so far to what I need.

Comment: I've not done it but I suspect if you inject a `NettyReactiveWebServerFactory` bean with a low @Order value then it would take precedence over the Tomcat one